# Dragon NaturallySpeaking: Application-specific voice commands don't work with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dragon-naturally-speaking

Application-specific voice commands don't work with Eclipse  with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5. I have defined a few voice commands for Eclipse, I tried to maintain available for Eclipse by editing their availability using the Command Browser (via browsing to `C:\programming\ide\eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64\eclipse.exe`) but to no avail:

[image]

I can't even choose Eclipse in the list:

[image]

Any idea how to make it work?

My Eclipse version: Kepler Service Release 1 (Build id: 20130919-0819). Also, globally defined voice commands do work well in Eclipse.

My task manager:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to see what other processes for eclipse there are in the Task Manager? Try tying the command to a different exe.

Comment: @user99572isfine Thanks, from what I can see there is only eclipse.exe, and the path is the same as the one I assigned to the command.

Comment: Do you have Dragon Pro or Premium?

Comment: I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking professional 12.5 English + French. Surprisingly everything was fine on my previous OS with Dragon NaturallySpeaking professional *11.5* English + French.

Comment: Was eclipse installed in the ProgramFiles or ProgramFiles (x86) folder on the previous OS? You might want to try that. And have you tried a repair install with Dragon? Setting up a new, 2nd profile to see if the error appears? If none of this works, you may have to resort to work-arounds.